# CorePlot - Change x-axis Label after calling barTouchUpAtRecordIndex:

Tags: ios, objective-c, bar-chart, core-plot, axis-labels

I have an iOS app that displays a CPTBarPlot. My plot bar responds to `barTouchUpAtRecordIndex:` by changing the background bar color but I also want to change the text label background and font color for that index. How can I change it?

[image]

Comment: The font color is part of the text style for the label. Are those axis labels or annotations?

Comment: They are custom axis labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font color is part of the text style for the label. `CPTTextLayer` (the layer class used to display text in Core Plot) is a subclass of `CPTBorderedLayer` so it can have a border line and a fill behind the text. Set the padding to control how much of the fill is visible around the text.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Eric for this great library!